# Update rows where field's value occurs more than once in table

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have table like this:

```
a b
1 0
2 0
2 0
2 0 
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
6 0
```

I would like to update field `b` to `1` in every row with `a`'s value occurring more then once in table, so I want to get something like this:

```
a b
1 0
2 1
2 1
2 1 
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 1
6 1
```

I only know how to select wanted rows with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`. I have no idea how to update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using update along with self join something as

```
update table_name t1
join (
  select 
  a,count(*) as cnt
  from table_name group by a
  having cnt > 1
)t2
on t1.a = t2.a
set t1.b=1
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |
|    2 |    0 |
|    2 |    0 |
|    2 |    0 |
|    3 |    0 |
|    4 |    0 |
|    5 |    0 |
|    6 |    0 |
|    6 |    0 |
+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update test t1
    -> join (
    ->   select 
    ->   a,count(*) as cnt
    ->   from test group by a
    ->   having cnt > 1
    -> )t2
    -> on t1.a = t2.a
    -> set t1.b=1 ;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    0 |
|    4 |    0 |
|    5 |    0 |
|    6 |    1 |
|    6 |    1 |
+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET b = 1
WHERE a IN (SELECT a 
            FROM (
               SELECT a 
               FROM mytable 
               GROUP BY a 
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x);
```

Note the use of the seemingly redundant sub-query: this is because MySQL won't let you *directly* specify target table `mytable` for update in `FROM` clause.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2df66/1)